# How to run a Scio pipeline on Dataflow from SBT (local)

Tags: scala, spotify-scio

I am trying to run my first **Scio** pipeline on **Dataflow** .

The code in question can be found [here](https://github.com/BalmungSan/scio-quickstart). However I do not think that is too important.
My first experiment was to read some local CSV files and write another local CSV file, using the **DirecRunner**. That worked as expected.

Now, I am trying to read the files from **GCS**, write the output to **BigQuery** and run the pipeline using the **DataflowRunner**. I already made all the necessary changes *(or that is what I believe)*. But I am unable to make it run.

I already `gcloud auth application-default login` and when I do

```
sbt run --runner=DataflowRunner --project=project-id --input-path=gs://path/to/data --output-table=dataset.table
```

I can see the Jb is submitted in **Dataflow**. However, after one hour the jobs fails with the following error message.

> Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h.

*(Note, the job did nothing in all that time, and since this is an experiment the data is simple too small to take more than a couple of minutes)*.

Checking the **StackDriver** I can find the follow error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Seq

Related to some **jackson** thing:

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule could not be instantiated

And that is what is killing each executor just at the start. I really do not understand why I can not find the Scala standard library.

I also tried to first create a template and runt it latter with:

```
sbt run --runner=DataflowRunner --project=project-id --input-path=gs://path/to/data --output-table=dataset.table --stagingLocation=gs://path/to/staging --templateLocation=gs://path/to/templates/template-1
```

But, after running the template, I get the same error.
Also, I noticed that in the **staging** folder there are a lot of jars, but the `scala-library.jar` is not in there.

I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known issue with sbt 1.3.0 which introduced some breaking change w.r.t. class loaders. Try 1.2.8?

Also the Jackson issue is probably related to Java 11 or above. Stay with Java 8 for now.

Comment: Thanks, that worked without problems. Just two questions, is the bug registered somewhere? I didn't find anything on the docs, nor on the github issue tracker. Second, I only have Java 8 installed on my machine, but I do not know which version fo java is the dataflow runner using, do I have control over that?

Comment: 1. Not yet (it's recent) but feel free to file one. 2. DF workers have JRE 8.

Comment: Here's the ticket https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/2280

Answer (score 4):

Fix by setting the sbt [`classLoaderLayeringStrategy`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/In-Process-Classloaders.html):

```
run / classLoaderLayeringStrategy := ClassLoaderLayeringStrategy.Flat
```

sbt uses a new classloader for the application that is run with `run`. This causes other classes already loaded by the JVM (Predef for instance) to be reused, reducing startup time. See [in-process classloaders](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/In-Process-Classloaders.html) for details.

This doesn't play well with the Beam DataflowRunner because it explicitly does not stage classes from parent classloaders, see [PipelineResources.java#L51](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.18.0/runners/core-construction-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/core/construction/PipelineResources.java#L51):

> Attempts to detect all the resources the class loader has access to. This does not recurse to class loader parents stopping it from pulling in resources from the system class loader.

So the fix is to force all classes used by your application to be loaded in the same classloader so that DataflowRunner stages everything.

Hope that helps

Comment: This was the fix for me. I had some library dependencies set in an object with classLoaderLayeringStrategy set, but a couple were being set outside of it. Moved them in and my the issue went away. Thanks!